# Understanding usage of eine/einer/.. to mean "one of the" but in specifically the gentive case

Tags: grammar-identification, article

> Ein(es) der wichtigsten Segelflugzentren ist in Deutschland bis heute die hessiche Wasserkuppe

The bracketted part was removed, and I am supposed to fill it in. I took it as "ein". Unfortunately it is wrong.

Why is it eines here?

I asked a similar question before [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74882/understanding-usage-of-eine-einer-to-mean-one-of-the) but I still have diffiuclty conceptualizing the article when it's in the gentive case like above.

Comment: *Eines* is not an article as the answer to your first question told you. It is also not genitive.

Comment: Then what is it? @RHa

Comment: To quote the answer to your first question: "In your example, "eine" is an indefinite pronoun." The same applies to *eines* in your current question.
Please read the answers to your questions carefully so that you don't have to ask again.

Comment: Ok that is fine, but the problem is thinking of the ending

Comment: Does this answer your question? [function of "eines" in "eines der größten Abwehr-Talente in Europa"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53079/function-of-eines-in-eines-der-gr%c3%b6%c3%9ften-abwehr-talente-in-europa)

Answer (score 1):

Spot and remember the *ein__ der* combination. That one means *one of the …*. That *ein__* is an indefinite pronoun and it must be declined according to the gender of the noun after *der* but the case required by the function of the whole item in the sentence.

- der Kasten, die Kiste, das Kästchen

Nominativ

- einer der Kästen
- eine der Kisten
- eines der Kästchen

Genitiv

- wegen eines der Kästen
- wegen einer der Kisten
- wegen eines der Kästchen

Dativ

- in einem der Kästen
- in einer der Kisten
- in einem der Kästchen

Akkusativ

- in einen der Kästen
- in eine der Kisten
- in eines der Kästchen

As you can see, that *der* never changes. That is because it's always genitive plural. You could only switch it for a different sort of determiner, e.g. *vieler*:

- in einem vieler Kästen
- in einer vieler Kisten
- in einem vieler Kästchen

Those mean *in one of many …*. Also, be aware that there is an alternative to using a genitive attribute:

- in einem von den Kästen
- in einer von den Kisten
- in einem von den Kästchen

And again e.g.

- in einem von vielen Kästen
- in einer von vielen Kisten
- in einem von vielen Kästchen

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have be an indefinite pronoun, it could be a *Numeral*: "eines der Zentren", "zwei der Zentren", ...